# Software for proving tautology with steps

Tags: logic, math-software

I'm looking for a software which can prove a tautology using logical equivalences.

Ideally, it can show each step. One step would be, for example, to use absorption, distributivity and the like.

Here is an example:
\begin{align}
(p\to q)\to(\neg q\to\neg p)&\equiv\neg(\neg p\lor q)\lor(q\lor\neg p)\tag{material implication}\\[1em]
&\equiv\neg(\neg p\lor q)\lor(\neg p\lor q)\tag{commutativity}\\[1em]
&\equiv \neg M\lor M\tag{$M:\neg p\lor q$}\\[1em]
&\equiv \mathbf{T}.\tag{negation law}
\end{align}

Comment: The Lean Theorem Prover https://leanprover.github.io/logic_and_proof/propositional_logic_in_lean.html is capable of handling propositional logic, but as far as I'm aware you need to actually tell it what steps to apply in a sort of programming language.

Comment: "Proving" a propositional formula is a tautology is coNP, it can't really be done faster than truth tables yet, so with software even "small" formulas can really blow up.